# Is there a way to disable the seeking bar of the google home app when casting?

Tags: google-cast, google-home, google-cast-sdk

When casting, google home app takes the session and acts as a controller. I need to disable or block or hide the seeking bar, so the user can't seek from google home app

[Element to disable in google home UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wi4z.jpg)

Is it possible to do this from the receiver app through the cast SDK?

I've not found anything on the cast SDK docs
Is there any docs that helps me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is controlled by the supportedMediaCommands being set, there is no way to control it using a default web receiver as the supported commands are set to ALL_BASIC_MEDIA which includes SEEK.

If you are currently implementing a custom web receiver you should be able to remove the seek command from it using PlayerManager. Check simple web receiver app JS code below:

```
const context = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();

const playerManager = context.getPlayerManager();

playerManager.removeSupportedMediaCommands(cast.framework.messages.Command.SEEK)

context.start();
```